# F# New Project Dialog does not show Console Application option

Tags: visual-studio, f#, console-application

I installed `Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6.5` (the latest) and now when I create a new `Visual F#` project under `.NET Standard` the only alternative is `Class Library (.NET Standard)`. I would like to create a `Console Application`. How can I do that?

Comment: you can still run the dll with `dotnet run`. If you want an exe create .net core app, then run `dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64` (if you're on windows), this will put the exe under the Release folder.

Comment: Try ".NET Core" instead of ".NET Standard".  ".NET Standard" is only meant to be used for libraries, not apps.